# Mesh become weird when added to vertex group

Tags: vertex-groups, mirror-modifier

im still new in using blender, i was following this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tI1uObIx4lM&ab_channel=3DJeffAllen) to make the model, but when i trying to add shoulder mesh to vertex group, the mesh become weird, the mesh has 2 mirror modifier (main & shoulder) and the one has problem is the shoulder mirror. I hope someone can help to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

[image: the model]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/185745RvH2boslpRQP4kAoraoRG7oSOUK?usp=sharing

Comment: tbh and i don't wanna be disrespectful, but if you are really new to Blender you shouldn't do such complicated things with a video which isn't made for beginners at all (and without voice explaining what he is doing). I recommend watching some of Polyfjords tutorials, which are beginner friendly and he explains what he is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The deformation comes from your armature, you haven't symmetrized your armature, so for the moment the bone called *Shoulder Armor.L* controlled the 2 shoulders, as soon as you rotate it, it also rotates the right shoulder. To fix that, symmetrize your armature and parent the right hand part of your robot to the right hand bones:

[image]